# query did not return a unique result:

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

im new to Spring Jpa and i have problem saying query did not return a unique result:18;

I have table orders and customer. Order table has a foreing key (customer_id_fk) to customers table. So in order table i can see all customers who have   ordered and what. But i need a query what will return me all  orders by (customer_id_fk). I already looked up this problem and it looks like when i search it, it can return one one uniqu id from customer table. But all i need is just find all those fk without accessing customers table.

For example like we are writing in MySQL ->select * From orders Where customer_id_fk =1; and it could show me only that data. But spring does not seem to understand it, i also tried to write Custom query but it did not work.

Is there a way i can do this ?

Data from MySQL

[image]

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order,Long> {

    @Override
    Iterable<Order> findAll();

    Order getOrdersByCustomerId(Long customerId);
}
```

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

    OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Autowired
    public OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }
 public Order findOrderByCustomerId(Long customerId) throws SQLException{
         return this.orderRepository.getOrdersByCustomerId(customerId);
    }

}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity

@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Date orderTime;
    private Double productCost;
    private Double subtotal;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "customer_id_fk",foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "customer_id")) 
    private  Customer customer; 

    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String postCode;

    @Enumerated (EnumType.STRING)
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

    private Integer quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "foodItem_id",foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "foodItem_id_fk"))
    private FoodItem foodItem;
 
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private Integer phoneNumber;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @OneToOne
    private CustomerAddress customerAddress;


}
```

Controller class:

```
@GetMapping("menu/{customerId}/orderHistory")
public String showOrderHistory(Model model, @PathVariable  Long customerId) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("customerId",customerId);
    Customer customer=customerService.findCustomerById(customerId);
    System.out.println("ccustomer iss: "+customer);

   Order order=  orderService.findOrderByCustomerId(customer.getId()); // query did not return a unique result: 18

    model.addAttribute("customerName",customer.getFirstName()+" "+customer.getLastName()); //this works
    // model.addAttribute("order",order);
   


    return "customer/orderHistory";
}
```

Comment: Your query, as your image as well as the error is telling you , returns more then 1 `Order`. Your method signature is returning `Order` which is for 1 row, you have 21 rows, how should that be shoehorned into 1 order? Instead return a `List<Order>` to obtain all the orders for a customer.

Comment: i tried to make it as List<Order> but it did not work, maybe i wrote it wrong

Comment: You changed it where? Please update your question, with the modified code and (if any) error (preferably the **full stacktrace**)

Comment: i dont know what kind of magic you and stackoverflow did but my code with list works now :D omg i guess i only needed to post :D thank you, now i also understood better diffrence between Order and List<Order>, i missed part where Order only returns one row

Comment: @M.Deinum your comment should be an Answer, and sarah6 can then accept it. That's how SO works - questions get answers, one of which is accepted by the question author so that others know what was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your own screenshot you see the query returns 21 rows. This is also what the exception/error is telling you (no unique result).

Your repository method returns a single `Order` whilst your query returns 21. That isn't going to fit. Instead you need to return a collection of orders, like `List<Order>`.

```java
List<Order> getOrdersByCustomerId(Long customerId);
```

An `Order` represents a row in the database, so in your case you will get a list with 21 `Order` objects in it.